# Process data depending on multiples observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have two observables from two differents HTTP calls.
In my component, I need to call those two services, process the data returned from these services and send two other variable that are the result of the proccessing to the template.

I have tried to much things that I can't put them all here, but here are the main solutions i've tried so far :

- Use forkJoin on the 2 services and then process the data : the function doing the process said the result was undefined.
- Use switchMap : same result as above.
- Use BehaviorSubject : same result again

I don't know if I forgot some elementary rule of Observable or RxJs in general, but I really can't find the right way to do it.

Here is my current code in my component :

```
  public notifGroups: any;
  public currentUser: any;
  public currentUserGroups: any;
  public notifGroupsImOut: any;

  private _notifGroupsImIn: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  public readonly notifGroupsImIn: any = this._notifGroupsImIn.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private _groupService: GroupService,
    private _currentUserService: CurrentUserService,
    private _userService: UserService,
  ) { }



  ngOnInit() {
     this.test().subscribe(
     res => {
      console.log(res);
      for(let mGroup in res[1]["user"]["subscriptionsToGroups"]){
        for(let nGroup in res[0]["list"]) {
          console.log(nGroup);
          console.log(mGroup);
          if (mGroup["group"]["email"] == nGroup["email"]){             
             this._notifGroupsImIn
                .next(this._notifGroupsImIn.getValue().push(nGroup));
          }
        }
      }
      this.notifGroupsImIn.subscribe()
    }
  )
}



  private _getNotifGroups(): any{
    return this._groupService
      .getGroupsByType('NOTIFICATION')
  }

  private _getCurrentUser() {
    return this._currentUserService
      .getCurrentUser()  
  }

  public getAll(){
    return Observable.forkJoin(this._getNotifGroups(), this._getCurrentUser())
  }

  public test(): Observable<Array<any>> {
     let obs = this.getAll();

     obs.subscribe(
         res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.notifGroups = res[0]["list"];
            this.currentUser = res[1]["user"]["subscriptionsToGroups"];
       }
    )
    return obs
 }
```

Well I know some parts of the code are quite dirty now, but I hope you won't mine too much.

So what I'm trying to do is :

I get the following values from the two services : notifGroups and currentUserGroups.

They are both list of objects.

then in my test() function, I compare each object with another, if the email property of this object is equal to the other's, I add it to notifGroupImIn.

But it's when the test() function is called, it looks like the results of the http calls are not resolved yet, even if i called them in ngOnInit and subscribed to them.

I'm not really sure if I was understandable enough, so please let me know.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've changed a bit my code, because in the template, notifGroupsImIn was still an observable. And now I Have the following error : Cannot read property 'email' of undefined. The email property where the error is raised is one of thoses two :

```
if (mGroup["group"]["email"] == nGroup["email"]){                  
  this._notifGroupsImIn.next(this._notifGroupsImIn.getValue().push(nGroup));
}
```

Also, the two lines

```
console.log(nGroup);
console.log(mGroup);
```

both return 0 in the console, can't figure why, as `res[1]["user"]["subscriptionsToGroups"]` and `res[0]["list"]` correctly returns a list of objects

Comment: Passing an array to `flatMap` will see the array's values emitted individually, but your snippet seems to expect an array to be emitted. That's not going to happen.

Comment: "two other variable that are the result of the proc(c)essing to the template." They are called what? Hard to read in first couple of lines what your question is. What are you looking to **achieve**. Needs to be more 'punchy'/to the point early on in post to hook reader..

Comment: Indeed i'm not really getting to the point. Actually my code is becoming a complete mess because of all the thing i've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example with `forkJoin`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 't-root',
  template: `
    <div>{{groups}}</div>
    <div>{{user}}</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  groups: any;
  user: any;

  // Assume this method calls this._groupService.getGroupsByType('NOTIFICATION')
  private _getNotifGroups(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of('GROUPS');
  }

  // Assume this method calls this._currentUserService.getCurrentUser()  
  private _getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of('USER');
  }

  private getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.forkJoin( this._getNotifGroups(), this._getCurrentUser() );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAll().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res); // ['GROUPS', 'USER']
      this.groups = res[0];
      this.user = res[1];
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this part already works for me, its when I try to process this data in my component that I fail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `combineLatest`

> **combineLatest**: Merges the specified observable sequences into one observable sequence by using the selector function whenever any of the observable sequences produces an element.

```
public getAll(){
   return Observable.combineLatest(
       this._getNotifGroups(), 
       this._getCurrentUser()
   );
}
```

`combineLatest` [Docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md)

If it doesn't work, please mention what was the error or why it didnt work.